# How to add value of column A if it exist on Table 2 using Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Mabuhay!

What is the most efficient or more convenient way to do this.

I have a select query and put it on a datagridview base on my filter. It has 5 columns. I want to know if Column CA from that Datagridview already exist on Table 2 which is on Column 3?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=sa;Password=pw");
            // DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            //dt = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT max(PurchaseOrder.POTitle) as Description,sum(PurchaseOrderEntry.Price *PurchaseOrderEntry.QuantityOrdered) as Amount, max(PurchaseOrder.PONumber)as PONumber, " +
                      " max(PurchaseOrderEntry.OrderNumber) as BoxCount, max(PurchaseOrderEntry.OrderNumber) as PLC,max(PurchaseOrderEntry.OrderNumber) as Branch, max(PurchaseOrderEntry.OrderNumber) as PreparedBy, max(PurchaseOrderEntry.OrderNumber) as CheckedBy " +
                      " FROM PurchaseOrder LEFT OUTER JOIN" +
                      " PurchaseOrderEntry ON PurchaseOrder.ID = PurchaseOrderEntry.PurchaseOrderID" +
                      " WHERE (PurchaseOrder.Remarks like '%" + tanggapan.Text + "%') AND (PurchaseOrder.DateCreated BETWEEN '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "' AND '" + dateTimePicker2.Text + "' and PurchaseOrder.OtherStoreID = '" + branch.Text + "') Group By PurchaseOrder.PONumber", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

This show my query filter. Any tip on how to do if **PurchaseOrderEntry.OrderNumber** already exist on my records so I can manage which one repeats.

Thank you!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I added this code now on my works and it is working now.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Clear();
 dt.Reset();

 con.Close();

 adaptors1.SelectCommand = con.CreateCommand();
 adaptors1.SelectCommand.CommandText = "Select TOP 1 [ponumber],[clref]  from [ISSPandayan].[dbo].[" + branch.Text + "] where [ponumber] = '" + dr.Cells["ponumber"].Value + "' ORDER BY [clref] ASC";
 adaptors1.Fill(dt); 

 // select query para malam kung existing ponumber
 if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
 {
     adaptorss.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@already", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
 }
 else
 {
     adaptorss.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@already", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = " ";
 }

 //adaptorss.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@already", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";

 //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(dr.Cells["description"].Value));
 con.Close();
 con.Open();

 adaptorss.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 adaptorss.InsertCommand.Parameters.Clear();
```